# Code coverage and Node coverage

Tags: testing

please help me to do these questions..

1.What is the the minimal set for 100% Node Coverage?

2.What's the coverage level of Edge coverage for the above given Test set?

`public static void bubbleSort(int[] numArray) {

```
int n = numArray.length;                           //NODE1
int temp = 0;                                      //NODE1

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                      //NODE2
    for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {            //NODE3
        if (numArray[j - 1] > numArray[j]) {       //NODE4
            temp = numArray[j - 1];                //NODE5
            numArray[j - 1] = numArray[j];         //NODE5
            numArray[j] = temp;                    //NODE5
        }
    }
}
```

Sysytem.ot.println("end");                            //NODE6
}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Any set with n>1 will cover 100% nodes.
2. There are 4 branches. Each branch is defined by a for/if statement.
   If your test sets goes though these branches, you pass 100% coverage.

I think you forget give us your 
"**above** given Test set"

For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage

Comment: sorry for the late reply,thanks a lot for your response